# Showing data in tableview from json

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this json response in postman...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "order_data": [
        {
            "order_id": "00145",
            "seller_id": "263",
            "customer_id": "101",
            "product_id": "8",
            "product_name": "casserole",
            "product_image": "http://myapp.com/public/uploads/products/123_45_6_image_123456789",
            "product_quantity": "79",
            "grand_total": "500",
            "discount_price": "0",
            "selling_price": "500",
            "shipping_charges": "0",
            "taxes": "0",
            "applied_coupon_code": "",
            "transaction_type": "COD",
            "mobile_number": "9876543210",
```

Now some response from this data has to be shown in my tableview. As a 1st step for that I'm parsing that data in the success block like so...

```
       Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                if let httpResponse = response.response {
                   if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
               if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                            if result["success"] as! Int == 0 {
                                print("Something went wrong!")
                          }  else if result["success"] as! Int == 1 {
             if let orderData = result["order_data"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                                    for order in orderData {
                                   guard let orderNo = order["order_id"] as? String,
                                              let status = order["order_status"] as? String,
                                            let orderPlacedDate = order["created_at"] as? String,
                                          let rate = order["selling_price"] as? String
                                            else {continue}


 //`Order` given below is a struct.                          
  let theOrder = Order(order_id: orderNo, selling_price: rate, order_status: status, created_at: orderPlacedDate)

self.orderData.append(theOrder)
```

And finally my `cellForRowAt`, `numberOfRowsInSection` & `noOfItems` is given as below...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: OrdersTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ordersIdentifier") as! OrdersTableViewCell

    let orderObj = orderData[indexPath.row]
    cell.orderNo.text = orderObj.order_id
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return orderData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

But my tableview is showing blank. Did I miss something..? Hope somebody can help...

Comment: You need to reload the tableView because the Alamofire webcall is async.

Comment: You were exactly right @Larme. Reloading the tableview made it work fine. Thanks...:) Do put this up as an answer so that I can accept it...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

after getting data in `orderData`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }

//Instead of tableView use your tableView name
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `reloadData` after appending all element in `orderData` array that is coming from API because it takes some time to get the response and your tableView `datasource` calls before appending the data:

```
for order in orderData {
 //....
}
self.YourTableView.reloadData()
```